# Controlling shader framerate

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, frame-rate

I've got a project that I'm writing a frag shader for and I want to be able to control the framerate. I'm kind of having trouble getting info on this - almost everything I've found on it is about optimizing framerate for 60-90fps, but what I need is actually to drop it to about 20fps.

Comment: Quick 'n dirty: `Sleep(50 milliseconds); SwapBuffers()`

Comment: can I do that in a frag shader? Going to add for clarification

Comment: Nope, that'll be in your client code.  No real way to slow down shader execution other than doing more work in them.

Comment: Why do you need to slow down *shader* execution?

Comment: I've been doing a series of retro video filters and I got a request for a specific filter. They sent me a video sample and told me that one of the key requirements was that it needs to be 20fps to achieve the effect.

Comment: I suppose I could figure out how to just change the framerate of the camera feed itself and then layer the rest of the shaders that I need on top of it

Comment: The normal way to change the FPS of video is actually change the FPS of the video (so temporal resampling), not just play it back with "controlled lag".

Comment: @harold Video and rendered content are different things

Comment: @MartinPerry clearly. But going by the comments, this is a video question.

Answer (score 0):

Doing anything with framerate is a bad design. What you should do is to change your update loop. Imagine it this way:

Your shader can render in 1000FPS, but you actually need 20FPS. If you will render static image, you wont notice if it is 20 or 1000FPS. However, if you need some sort of movement, you will notice. So, instead of updating shader variable (responsible for the movement) every frame, update it in only every n-th frame and it should give you the desired effect,

See something about game loops, eg: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25767/is-it-safe-to-set-fps-rate-to-a-constant

Comment: it may be bad design, but it's kind of my only option here. I did find this shadertoy: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llS3Rc which seems to have some relevant stuff in it, but I'm trying to figure out how to use it without the color artifacts.